# Unable to retrain the instance segmentation model

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, image-segmentation, tfrecord

Im trying to train the instance segmentation model. Im using the following code to generate the tfrecord.

```
flags = tf.app.flags
flags.DEFINE_string('data_dir', '', 'Root directory to raw pet dataset.')
flags.DEFINE_string('output_dir', '', 'Path to directory to output TFRecords.')
flags.DEFINE_string('label_map_path', 'data/pet_label_map.pbtxt',
                    'Path to label map proto')
flags.DEFINE_boolean('faces_only', True, 'If True, generates bounding boxes '
                     'for pet faces.  Otherwise generates bounding boxes (as '
                     'well as segmentations for full pet bodies).  Note that '
                     'in the latter case, the resulting files are much larger.')
flags.DEFINE_string('mask_type', 'png', 'How to represent instance '
                    'segmentation masks. Options are "png" or "numerical".')
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS


def get_class_name_from_filename(file_name):

  match = re.match(r'([A-Za-z_]+)(_[0-9]+\.jpg)', file_name, re.I)
  return match.groups()[0]


def dict_to_tf_example(data,
                       mask_path,
                       label_map_dict,
                       image_subdirectory,
                       ignore_difficult_instances=False,
                       faces_only=True,
                       mask_type='png'):

  img_path = os.path.join(image_subdirectory, data['filename'])
  with tf.gfile.GFile(img_path, 'rb') as fid:
    encoded_jpg = fid.read()
  encoded_jpg_io = io.BytesIO(encoded_jpg)
  image = PIL.Image.open(encoded_jpg_io)
  if image.format != 'JPEG':
    raise ValueError('Image format not JPEG')
  key = hashlib.sha256(encoded_jpg).hexdigest()

  with tf.gfile.GFile(mask_path, 'rb') as fid:
    encoded_mask_png = fid.read()
  encoded_png_io = io.BytesIO(encoded_mask_png)
  mask = PIL.Image.open(encoded_png_io)
  if mask.format != 'PNG':
    raise ValueError('Mask format not PNG')

  mask_np = np.asarray(mask)
  nonbackground_indices_x = np.any(mask_np != 2, axis=0)
  nonbackground_indices_y = np.any(mask_np != 2, axis=1)
  nonzero_x_indices = np.where(nonbackground_indices_x)
  nonzero_y_indices = np.where(nonbackground_indices_y)

  width = int(data['size']['width'])
  height = int(data['size']['height'])

  xmins = []
  ymins = []
  xmaxs = []
  ymaxs = []
  classes = []
  classes_text = []
  truncated = []
  poses = []
  difficult_obj = []
  masks = []
  if 'object' in data:
    for obj in data['object']:
      difficult = bool(int(obj['difficult']))
      if ignore_difficult_instances and difficult:
        continue
      difficult_obj.append(int(difficult))

      if faces_only:
        xmin = float(obj['bndbox']['xmin'])
        xmax = float(obj['bndbox']['xmax'])
        ymin = float(obj['bndbox']['ymin'])
        ymax = float(obj['bndbox']['ymax'])
      else:
        xmin = float(np.min(nonzero_x_indices))
        xmax = float(np.max(nonzero_x_indices))
        ymin = float(np.min(nonzero_y_indices))
        ymax = float(np.max(nonzero_y_indices))

      xmins.append(xmin / width)
      ymins.append(ymin / height)
      xmaxs.append(xmax / width)
      ymaxs.append(ymax / height)
      class_name = get_class_name_from_filename(data['filename'])
      classes_text.append(class_name.encode('utf8'))
      classes.append(label_map_dict[class_name])
      truncated.append(int(obj['truncated']))
      poses.append(obj['pose'].encode('utf8'))
      if not faces_only:
        mask_remapped = (mask_np != 2).astype(np.uint8)
        masks.append(mask_remapped)

  feature_dict = {
      'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(height),
      'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(width),
      'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(
          data['filename'].encode('utf8')),
      'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(
          data['filename'].encode('utf8')),
      'image/key/sha256': dataset_util.bytes_feature(key.encode('utf8')),
      'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_jpg),
      'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature('jpeg'.encode('utf8')),
      'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
      'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
      'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
      'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs),
      'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
      'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
      'image/object/difficult': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(difficult_obj),
      'image/object/truncated': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(truncated),
      'image/object/view': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(poses),
  }
  if not faces_only:
    if mask_type == 'numerical':
      mask_stack = np.stack(masks).astype(np.float32)
      masks_flattened = np.reshape(mask_stack, [-1])
      feature_dict['image/object/mask'] = (
          dataset_util.float_list_feature(masks_flattened.tolist()))
    elif mask_type == 'png':
      encoded_mask_png_list = []
      for mask in masks:
        img = PIL.Image.fromarray(mask)
        output = io.BytesIO()
        img.save(output, format='PNG')
        encoded_mask_png_list.append(output.getvalue())
      feature_dict['image/object/mask'] = (
          dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(encoded_mask_png_list))

  example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature_dict))
  return example


def create_tf_record(output_filename,
                     label_map_dict,
                     annotations_dir,
                     image_dir,
                     examples,
                     faces_only=True,
                     mask_type='png'):

  writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(output_filename)
  for idx, example in enumerate(examples):
    if idx % 100 == 0:
      logging.info('On image %d of %d', idx, len(examples))
    xml_path = os.path.join(annotations_dir, 'xmls', example + '.xml')
    mask_path = os.path.join(annotations_dir, 'trimaps', example + '.png')

    if not os.path.exists(xml_path):
      logging.warning('Could not find %s, ignoring example.', xml_path)
      continue
    with tf.gfile.GFile(xml_path, 'r') as fid:
      xml_str = fid.read()
    xml = etree.fromstring(xml_str)
    data = dataset_util.recursive_parse_xml_to_dict(xml)['annotation']

    try:
      tf_example = dict_to_tf_example(
          data,
          mask_path,
          label_map_dict,
          image_dir,
          faces_only=faces_only,
          mask_type=mask_type)
      writer.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())
    except ValueError:
      logging.warning('Invalid example: %s, ignoring.', xml_path)

  writer.close()


# TODO(derekjchow): Add test for pet/PASCAL main files.
def main(_):
  data_dir = FLAGS.data_dir
  label_map_dict = label_map_util.get_label_map_dict(FLAGS.label_map_path)

  logging.info('Reading from Pet dataset.')
  image_dir = os.path.join(data_dir, 'images')
  annotations_dir = os.path.join(data_dir, 'annotations')
  examples_path = os.path.join(annotations_dir, 'trainval.txt')
  examples_list = dataset_util.read_examples_list(examples_path)

  # Test images are not included in the downloaded data set, so we shall perform
  # our own split.
  random.seed(42)
  random.shuffle(examples_list)
  num_examples = len(examples_list)
  num_train = int(0.7 * num_examples)
  train_examples = examples_list[:num_train]
  val_examples = examples_list[num_train:]
  logging.info('%d training and %d validation examples.',
               len(train_examples), len(val_examples))

  train_output_path = os.path.join(FLAGS.output_dir, 'pet_train.record')
  val_output_path = os.path.join(FLAGS.output_dir, 'pet_val.record')
  if FLAGS.faces_only:
    train_output_path = os.path.join(FLAGS.output_dir,
                                     'pet_train_with_masks.record')
    val_output_path = os.path.join(FLAGS.output_dir,
                                   'pet_val_with_masks.record')
  create_tf_record(
      train_output_path,
      label_map_dict,
      annotations_dir,
      image_dir,
      train_examples,
      faces_only=FLAGS.faces_only,
      mask_type=FLAGS.mask_type)
  create_tf_record(
      val_output_path,
      label_map_dict,
      annotations_dir,
      image_dir,
      val_examples,
      faces_only=FLAGS.faces_only,
      mask_type=FLAGS.mask_type)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  tf.app.run()
```

The dataset that Im using to train has 37 classes with images and masks. The dataset is in [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_pets.md)

However when i try to train, Im getting the following error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "train.py", line 167, in
>   
>       tf.app.run()   File "/anaconda3/envs/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py",
>   line 126, in run
>       _sys.exit(main(argv))   File "train.py", line 163, in main
>       worker_job_name, is_chief, FLAGS.train_dir)   File "/Users/Documents/research/models/research/object_detection/trainer.py",
>   line 275, in train
>       clones = model_deploy.create_clones(deploy_config, model_fn, [input_queue])   File
>   "/Users/Documents/research/models/research/slim/deployment/model_deploy.py",
>   line 193, in create_clones
>       outputs = model_fn(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/Documents/research/models/research/object_detection/trainer.py",
>   line 200, in _create_losses
>       losses_dict = detection_model.loss(prediction_dict, true_image_shapes)   File
>   "/Users/Documents/research/models/research/object_detection/meta_architectures/faster_rcnn_meta_arch.py",
>   line 1608, in loss
>       groundtruth_masks_list,   File "/Users/Documents/research/models/research/object_detection/meta_architectures/faster_rcnn_meta_arch.py",
>   line 1837, in _loss_box_classifier
>       raise ValueError('Groundtruth instance masks not provided. ' ValueError: Groundtruth instance masks not provided. Please configure

How can I be able to sort it out?

Comment: seems you are not loading the groundtruth, you are only reading images without correspoding masks

Comment: when Im trying to print while loading,it is printing the path for mask too :(

Comment: i think you should debugg from here , it seems groundtruth_masks_list is empty if prediction_masks is not None:
        if groundtruth_masks_list is None:
          raise ValueError('Groundtruth instance masks not provided. '
                           'Please configure input reader.')

Comment: I have tried debugging it but I'm not able to append the mask.  Can you please tell me how I can append masks as well while creating tf records?

Comment: @user1241241 did you solve it?it happen the same to me

Comment: i could not too add the mask, but i change faces_only, because to true it does not append the mask it is explained in configuration file

Comment: but mask is not displayed, no one answer me i don't know what to do

Comment: @Aitul yes..I managed to solve it

Comment: @user1241241 How did you solve it? I facing same issue with coco dataset?

Comment: @user1241241 how did you solve it?  Facing same issue here.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the `tfrecord` creation was fine.  Similar to that which the OP has posted.  The solution to the problem was that I needed to add two lines in the `pipeline.config` file.

```
train_input_reader {
  label_map_path: "path/to/pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "path/to/traindata.tfrecord"
  }
  load_instance_masks: true
  mask_type: PNG_MASKS
}
```

The two lines `load_instance_masks: true` and `mask_type: PNG_MASKS` must be added to the `train_input_reader`.  This doesn't come by default in the `pipeline.config` file from model zoo.

Hope this helps.